# Optimize script with Pyodbc method

Tags: python, sql-server, optimization, pyodbc

In order to fetch some data I need to later processing with Matlab, I'm using a python script to extract that data from a series of over 50 identical databases (i.e. all sharing the same table structure)

I was able to to that with the code below. However, in order to avoid creating empty text files (due to the fact that some of those databases have no relevant data at all), I do run the query at first just to check if it returns empty or not and then I'm forced to run it again to get the data itself and write it to a file.

```py
import thesis,pyodbc

# SQL Server settings
drvr = '{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}'
host = 'POLIVEIRA-PC\\MSSQLSERVER2008'
user = 'username'
pswd = 'password'

# Establish a connection to SQL Server
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=drvr, server=host, uid=user, pwd=pswd) # Setup connection

# Prepare condition
tags = thesis.sensors().keys()
condition = ' WHERE Tag_ID=' + tags[0]
for tag in tags[1:]:
    condition += ' OR Tag_ID=' + tag

# Extract data from each database
for db in thesis.db_list():
    # Prepare query
    table = '[' + db + '].dbo.tBufferAux'
    query  = 'SELECT Data, Tag_ID, Valor FROM ' + table + condition + ' ORDER BY Data ASC'
    # Check if query's output is empty
    if not cnxn.cursor().execute(query).fetchone():
        print db, 'has no records!'
        continue # If so, jump to next database
    # Otherwise, save query's output to text file
    filename = 'Dataset_' + db + '.txt'
    filepath = thesis.out_dir() + filename
    with open(filepath,'w') as file:
        for record in cnxn.cursor().execute(query):
            file.write(str(record.Data) + ' ' + str(record.Tag_ID) + ' ' + str(record.Valor) + '\n')

# Close session
cnxn.cursor().close()
cnxn.close()
```

Although this code is running fine and finishing in about 20 seconds, I am curious about whether there are any way to optimize this script by avoiding repeating the query execution, that is, by avoiding calling `cnxn.cursor().execute(query)` twice.

Btw, I'm pretty new to both Python and SQL, so I'd be thankful if you could find something wrong or not viewed as a good practice in my code and tell me.

Comment: One option would be to call `recs = cnxn.cursor().execute(query).fetchall()` and then check whether `recs` is empty or not and operate accordingly. However, I wanted to avoid using `fetchall()` since it could stress my memory if there was a lot of rows.

Comment: How about storing that one row into a variable and if it exists, then just continue with fetchone until everything has been processed?

Comment: @JamesZ That actually crossed my mind, but then I would "sacrifice" the first row to check if it was empty... or maybe not, maybe I could've think a bit more on that and find a solution to avoid sacrificing the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest you check out pymssql, it's got some nice features pyodbc doesn't.

Second I would even more strongly suggest looking into Sql Server bcp or SSIS. They're built for this sort of thing and will be WAY more efficient than using python.

Third, if all the dbs are on the same server, you could actually do the whole thing in T-SQL using master.sys.databases and push the work to the server.

With that in mind:

```
import thesis,pyodbc

# SQL Server settings
drvr = '{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}'
host = 'POLIVEIRA-PC\\MSSQLSERVER2008'
user = 'username'
pswd = 'password'

# Establish a connection to SQL Server
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=drvr, server=host, uid=user, pwd=pswd) # Setup     connection

# Prepare condition
tags = thesis.sensors().keys()
condition = ' WHERE Tag_ID=' + tags[0]
for tag in tags[1:]:
    condition += ' OR Tag_ID=' + tag

# Extract data from each database
for db in thesis.db_list():
    # Prepare query
    table = '[' + db + '].dbo.tBufferAux'
    query  = 'SELECT Data, Tag_ID, Valor FROM ' + table + condition + '    ORDER BY Data ASC'
    # Check if query's output is empty
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        print db, 'has no records!'
    else:
        filename = 'Dataset_' + db + '.txt'
        filepath = thesis.out_dir() + filename
        with open(filepath,'w') as file:
            while cursor.fetchone():
                file.write(str(record.Data) + ' ' + str(record.Tag_ID) + ' ' + str(record.Valor) + '\n')

# Close session
cnxn.close()
```

A few more stylistic things:

1. Avoid continue wherever possible, use if-else for control flow
2. Pyodbc cursors can execute multiple queries and persit around. You don't need to create a new one each time you execute a query.
3. The cursor 'remembers' the last query it executed.
4. I suspect you will be sad if you use space delimited files... I speak from experience... :(
5. Cursors are automatically closed when they go out of scope, so cursor.close() if never necessary.

Comment: Well, I actually tried pymssql but I was getting to much difficulties to connect to the sql server, so I gave up and turned to pyodbc which worked out-of-the-box. Didn't know about bcp nor SSIS, I may give a look those in a future project. About the data files, how would you advise me delimit values? Using a comma?

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong, but the `record` variable is not set inside the `while` block, right?